# Send Email to Business Based on Product Dropdown Selection

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a Woocommerce product that I'd like to send the standard Woocommerce Order Confirmation Email to both the site admin and to a business if it is selected from a dropdown field on that product page.

### Backpack $50

Choose an Option

- Business First
- Business Second
- Business Third

If they select **Business First** than an order confirmation email will be sent to **Business First's** email info@businessfirst.com

This is the code I have so far

## HTML

```
<select name="wapf[field_5f87355d578fd]" class="wapf-input" data-is-required="" data-field-id="5f87355d578fd">
    <option value="">Choose an option</option>
    <option value="business_1">Business 1</option>
    <option value="business_2">Business 2</option>
    <option value="business_3">Business 3</option>
</select>
```

## PHP

I've added this to functions.php

```
function sv_conditional_email_recipient( $recipient, $order ) {

    // Bail on WC settings pages since the order object isn't yet set yet
    // Not sure why this is even a thing, but shikata ga nai
    $page = $_GET['page'] = isset( $_GET['page'] ) ? $_GET['page'] : '';
    if ( 'wc-settings' === $page ) {
        return $recipient; 
    }

    // just in case
    if ( ! $order instanceof WC_Order ) {
        return $recipient; 
    }

    $items = $order->get_items();

    // check if a shipped product is in the order   
    foreach ( $items as $item ) {
        $product = $order->get_product_from_item( $item );

        // adds our extra recipient if customer selected Business 1 from the dropdown on this product order
        if (select(name="wapf[field_5f87355d578fd]") value == "business_1") {
            $recipient .= ', info@businessfirst.com';
            return $recipient;
        }

        // adds our extra recipient if customer selected Business 2 from the dropdown on this product order
        if (select(name="wapf[field_5f87355d578fd]") value == "business_2") {
            $recipient .= ', info@businesssecond.com';
            return $recipient;
        }
    }

    return $recipient;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_new_order', 'sv_conditional_email_recipient', 10, 2 );
```

I think I'm close, but I don't have it quite right.

Comment: What does "not quite right" mean?  Is there an error that is thrown?

Comment: Where is this filter defined? `new_order` it's not in WooCommerce, or a function called `select()`

Comment: @HowardE I just updated my code to reflect the correct filter. The `select()` area is where I'm a bit lost. What I'm trying to do is send an additional new order email out to an email address of my choosing when a product is purchased where the user selected from a `select `dropdown with the `name="wapf[field_5f87355d578fd]"` an `option` with the value `business_1`

Comment: You don't have debugging enabled when you are doing this, since `select` is not a function.  This should throw some kind of error.  You need to find the values of your stored data for each order item.  This statement `(select(name="wapf[field_5f87355d578fd]") value == "business_1")` will never return true.

Comment: The problem with your whole question is that the HTML output of your `<select>` on the product page isn't what is relevant, but rather - where is the data stored?  Is it stored as order item meta, or what?  Are you using plugins to add this dropdown, or ACF? Once the item is added to cart, the fact that it was at one point `$_POST[ 'wapf[field_5f87355d578fd]']` isn't relevant anymore... Where is the additional information stored?  This is what you need to retrieve that field.  So I'd be debugging the cart data first, then the order data.

Answer (score 0):

Do you only want to mail them if they choose Business 1, or should they also be able to mail Business 2 or 3? If so, you need to put the if statement within the function, with two else if's for the other cases.

Also, if you're trying to get the value of a field you can't have a whitespace there.  `select(name="wapf[field_5f87355d578fd]") value`

[This blogpost](https://www.skyverge.com/blog/add-woocommerce-email-recipients-conditionally/) describes precisely what you need I think.

Comment: I want to also be able to email Business 2, Business 3, ect...

Comment: The blog I mentioned tells you exactly how to do just that. :)

Comment: It's damn near close. I just updated it. I don't think I have the if statement correct under `// adds our extra recipient if there's customer selected Business 1 from the dropdown on any product`

I'm trying to figure out how to send the email only when user selects an option from a dropdown of a product. 

The product is here that I'm trying to do this with: https://rootmeals.wpengine.com/product/meals-donation/ The field I'm trying to achieve this with the the **Agency** dropdown.

Comment: Then you should add an if statement to check if the select field is not empty, and if it's not, use If statements to check what option was chosen.